# found error in laravel 5.4, Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

In the admin area, I am trying to display the products in a listing page. Each product has category, color, size and type of the material 
My tables structure

```
categories
id   | category_name  
1    | Cat1  
2    | Cat2 

colors
id   |  color_name  
1    |  Color1   
2    |  Color2

materials
id   | material_type  
1    | material1  
2    | material2 

 sizes
id   | size_name  
1    | size1  
2    | size2
```

My product table

```
products
id  name  description category_id  color_id   material_id   size_id
1   pro1  product 1        1          1           1            1
2   pro2  product 2        2          2           2            2
```

Category Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Product;


class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function products(){
      return $this->hasOne(Product::class);
    }
}
```

color, size and material Models have the same structure

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Product;

class Color extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'colors';
    public function products(){
      return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

In the product controller, I have the following index function to display the products

```
public function index()
    {
      $products = Product::with('categories', 'colors' , 'sizes', 
      'materials', 'fantasias')->get();
      return view('backend.product.product-library', compact('products'));
    }
```

I would like the output to be

```
products
name  description  category   color    material   size 
pro1  product 1      cat1    color1    mateial1   size1
pro2  product 2      cat2    color2    material2  size2
```

My View is

```
  @foreach( $products as $item )
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><h3>{{ $item->product_name }}</h3></td>
          <td><p>{{ $item->product_description }}</p></td>
          <td><p>{{ $item->categories->category_name }}</p></td>
          <td><p>{{ $item->colors->color_name }}</p></td>
          <td><p>{{ $item->materials->material_type }}</p></td>
          <td><p>{{ $item->sizes->size_name }}</p></td>
          <td rowspan="2">
            <a class="btn transparent" href="{{ route('products.edit', ['product'=>$item->id]) }}">Edit</a>
            <form action="{{ route('products.destroy', ['product'=>$item->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
              <button type="submit" class="btn transparent">Delete</button>
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    @endforeach
```

The following error appears

```
ErrorException in b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php line 28:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/pet/resources/views/backend/product/product-library.blade.php)
```

Thank you so much for the help,

The full Error is

```
ErrorException in b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php line 28:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/pet/resources/views/backend/product/product-library.blade.php)
in b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php line 28
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), 1) in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/pet/storage/framework/views/b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'products' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/pet/resources/views/backend/product/product-library.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'products' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/var/www/html/pet/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
1/2
ErrorException in b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php line 28:
Trying to get property of non-object
in b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php line 28
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/var/www/html/pet/storage/framework/views/b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php', 28, array('__path' => '/var/www/html/pet/storage/framework/views/b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'products' => object(Collection)), 'obLevel' => 1, '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'products' => object(Collection), '__currentLoopData' => object(Collection), 'item' => object(Product), 'loop' => object(stdClass))) in b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php line 28
at include('/var/www/html/pet/storage/framework/views/b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/pet/storage/framework/views/b5a959a09cc5b7e6abf71778d058119094681a2d.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'products' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/pet/resources/views/backend/product/product-library.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'products' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 137
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 38
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 225
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 602
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 51
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/var/www/html/pet/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

This what I get when I var_dump($products) in the product controller

```
Collection {#305 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => Product {#313 ▶}
    1 => Product {#314 ▶}
    2 => Product {#315 ▶}
    3 => Product {#316 ▶}
    4 => Product {#317 ▶}
    5 => Product {#318 ▶}
    6 => Product {#319 ▼
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      #table: "products"
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:13 [▶]
      #original: array:13 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:5 [▼
        "categories" => Category {#303 ▶}
        "colors" => Color {#304 ▶}
        "sizes" => Size {#321 ▶}
        "materials" => Material {#307 ▶}
        "fantasias" => Fantasia {#124 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try by replacing these lines:

```
<td><p>{{ $item->categories->category_name }}</p></td>
<td><p>{{ $item->colors->color_name }}</p></td>
<td><p>{{ $item->materials->material_type }}</p></td>
<td><p>{{ $item->sizes->size_name }}</p></td>
```

with thse lines:

```
<td><p>{{ isset($item->categories) ? $item->categories->category_name: '-'}}</p></td>
<td><p>{{ isset($item->colors) ? $item->colors->color_name : '-'}}</p></td>
<td><p>{{ isset($item->materials) ? $item->materials->material_type : '-'}}</p></td>
<td><p>{{ isset($item->sizes) ? $item->sizes->size_name : '-'}}</p></td>
```

I think you got my point. Before accessing any property of an object, just check if that object is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here in the view

`<img src="{!! '/images/product-feature/'.$item->product_preview !!}">`

try with

`<img src="/images/product-feature/{!! $item->product_preview !!}`

Comment: @AhmedJalal Which line of the view you posted is the 28? In your products table (as described above), you don't have field named  product_preview, so what is that?

Comment: , My bad I had this field when I had an image in the product table but then I changed my mind and I will make a separate table for the images, but also without this line of code the issue persists, the same error comes even without the image line of code. sorry for the late response

Comment: No I didnt solve it it was my mistake adding the image line of code,, the issue still there and I cant solve it, thanks

Comment: Sorry I didn't read well your comment. Can you post which one is line 28?

Comment: you can try also adding `protected $fillable = [
   'column_name',
   'column_name',
   'column_name',
];` with the columns name in your models

Comment: more I think you have to check also these lines `<td><p>{{ $item->materials->color_name }}</p></td>
          <td><p>{{ $item->sizes->color_name }}</p></td>` cause you're trying to get the same field as the one before. Should be respectively `{{ $item->materials->materials_type }}` and `{{ $item->sizes->size_name }}`

Comment: Can you please post the full error, no only the first two lines?

Comment: I added the error in the question 

Thank you so much

Comment: Ok the problem could be when you're passing route with product. Instead of passing it as `{{ route('products.edit', ['product'=>$item->id]) }}` try with `{{ route('products.edit', $item->id) }}` and the same for `destroy`, change `{{ route('products.destroy', ['product'=>$item->id]) }}` to `{{ route('products.destroy', $item->id) }}`

Comment: No the same issue, maybe it just doesn't work like this What do you think if I make a sperate controller for every attribute is good practice Thank you so  much for your time I really appreciate your help, @Angus Simons

Comment: also I added what I get when  I var_dump $products in the contoller